# Rails 5 error: ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant PagesController):

Tags: ruby, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-5

I am a newbie and I am trying to learn Rails and I am taking a online tutorial and I am stuck early. The instructor is not much help. My paths/routes look ok to me and my naming convention seems to be ok. I have looked at others on here with similar issues and I can't seem to understand whats going on. Any guidance would be helpful.

[my routs.rb file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yJeD.png)

Thank You.

Comment: Check the name of pages controller, maybe it's PageController..

Comment: Have you got a file `app/controllers/pages_controller.rb` and the first line is `PagesController < ApplicationController` ?  If you don't, that's your problem.

Comment: Sorry, for not including this, my pages_controller.rb     class PagesController < ApplicationController

 def home
 end
    
    def about
 end

 def help
 end
 
 
end

Comment: Your routes looks fine.  Check that the controller is in the controllers folder and not a sub folder.  And hi to Steve, hope you're well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was i didn't declare the page constant in a model. 
Thank you all for your responses.